# Snap windows to 1/3 of screen

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, display, dualhead

I've got two monitors side-by-side, one in landscape, and the other in portrait mode. For the portrait monitor, I would love to be able to snap windows to the bottom, middle, and top thirds of the screen. Halves is too much vertical screen space for most things I work on. Is there an application to customize the snap behavior to that extent?

Ubuntu 17.10

Comment: You can control the position and size of the windows in Xorg with the program `wmctrl`. See `man wmctrl` and  maybe find some tutorials that give detailed examples via the internet. Install from the repositories with `sudo apt install wmctrl`

Answer (score 7):

Have a look at the gnome extension "[gTile](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/28/gtile/)".

From the readme:

> Gnome-shell extension that improves window tiling capabilities of stock gnome-shell.
>   gTile is used to moves/resize windows on a configurable grid scheme.

When you click on the gTile icon it will open a dialog that lets you draw a region on an e. g. `1x3` grid. Once you have drawn the region gTile will move and resize the currently active windows to match that region on the real screen.

You can configure a hot key (for instance <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>) to send the current window to a specific field in an `NxM` grid. In your case it could be the first field in a `1x3` grid. Likewise for the other two windows.

Comment: Thanks! Especially shortcuts without gui are great: https://github.com/gTile/gTile#usage-with-no-interface Placement format is underdocumented, it goes like this: `{grid_width}x{grid_height} {start_x}:{start_y} {end_x}:{end_y}`.

Comment: it's a bit weird to have to install this via a web browser extension (I would have expected some `apt install` instead, but anyway seems to work well. It also seems much, much more powerful than what I had in mind -- which is what the OP was asking for (just snap to thirds). Very interesting; opens horizons :-)